# Redirecting from one form to another form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, request

I have two form pages:

1. Start Form - where you input the basic information
2. Add product form - uses data from start form to populate some fields. And there you can also give more information in the form.

In the urls.py I have this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',add_product_start),
    url(r'^add_product/$', add_product),
    )
```

This is my add_product_start form view:

```
def add_product_start(request):
    form = add_product_start_form()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = add_product_start_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            #return respose to the add_product url with request data
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})
```

And this is my add_product view:

```
def add_product(request):
    images = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        initial = {field:value for (field,value) in request._post.iteritems() if value}
        #a bunch of other code
        #point is I want to receive post data from add_product_start view and at the same time redirect to a different url, because I don't want to have the same url of two different forms.
    return render(request,'add_product.html' ,{'form':form,'images':images})
```

I know there is something like HttpResponseRedirect but they just redirect me to the page without any type of data.I want to get the data from the start form, validate it, and if valid pass it to the second view with a different page.

Can someone please help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using the form wizard https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Comment: Located in the external package [django-formtools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-formtools) in 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar issue using redirect(obj).
This video may help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsHd-l7QdI8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).